# How to remove BindableProperty from BindableObject in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to remove BindableProperty from BindableObject?

**I mean the reversal of the process:**

```
BindableProperty property = BindableProperty.Create(…)
```

Comment: Seems like an [X-Y-Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. What is your rationale to remove the bindable property? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to add a BindableProperty, use it for some time, and when I do not need it anymore, I want to release memory / resources.

Comment: It may not be allowed because it is difficult to determine who uses this DependencyProperty, which could result in further exceptions.

I do not see any other reason for not having a simple method to remove BindableProperty, since I can create it myself.

Comment: Yeah it's very error prone and the merit is in doubt. Have you conducted a memory profiling to assure that keeping *this one instance* (it's `static` after all) is an issue?

Comment: You're right, it does not make sense. The answer to my question probably sounds so - there is no way to remove BindableProperty, but it's probably good in most cases. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `RemoveBinding()`

From the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindableobject.removebinding?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_BindableObject_RemoveBinding_Xamarin_Forms_BindableProperty_

Comment: This method removes some Binding from some BindableProperty but leaves the BindableProperty in the BindableObject. Am I right?